# Open a float context menu from an action bar menu option

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-menu

I want to create a float context menu that shows when the user taps on an specific option from the action bar. This is my diagram made on a whiteboard.

[image]

I dont have time for using a mockup tool. I'm a beginner in android but I was doing some research about it. However, I have just came up with my action bar.

[image]

I found many tutorials are so complicated that I can not follow them.
**What would be a good way to start coding this feature?**

Comment: use submenu. Also u can use dialog with list items.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting solution anyway :)

See adding list into alert dialog in given link [AlertDialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog)

in **menu.xml** add items like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="menu_item"
    app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu1"
            android:title="menu1"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu2"
            android:title="menu2"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

and in activity onOptionsItemSelected()

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    ...
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu2)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Submenu").setItems(new String[]
        {
        "Item1", "Item2", "Item3"
        }, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {//TODO
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
    ...

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This will solve the purpose!